# pagina web php consulta de iniciar secion

Tags: php

Si me puede ayudar cree un inicio de sesion en una pagina web, pero cuando deseo iniciar la pagina me muestra el codigo implementado mas no a donde me debe dirigir.

```php
<?php

include("Conexion.php");

$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$apellidos = $_POST["apellidos"];
$fechaingreso =$_POST["fechaingreso"];
$celular = $_POST["celular"];
$tarea = $_POST["tarea"];
$fechaconsignacion = $_POST["fechaconsignacion"];
$valor=$_POST["valor"];
$referido=$_POST["referido"];
$contrasena = $_POST["contrasena"];

$passwordHash = password_hash($contrasena, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

$consultaId = "SELECT nombre from usuario WHERE nombre='$nombre' ";

$consultaId = mysqli_query($conexion, $consultaId);

$consultaId = mysqli_fetch_array($consultaId);

if(!$consultaId){

    $sql = "INSERT INTO usuario VALUES ('$nombre', '$apellidos', '$fechaingreso', '$celular','$tarea','$fechaconsignacion','$valor','$referido','$passwordHash')";
    if (mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)){

        mkdir("../img/$nombre");
        copy("../img/usuario.png","../img/$nombre/perfil.png");
        echo "Tu informacion ha sido enviada.";

    } else{
        echo "Error: " .$sql. "<br>" . mysqli_error($conexion);
    }
}else{
    echo"El nombre ya existe.";
    echo "<a href='usuario.html'> Intentalo de nuevo. </a></div>";
}

mysqli_close($conexion);

?>
```

Comment: Te recomendaría que añadieras el código que desarrollaste para que podamos ayudarte!.

Comment: Cuando dices que te **muestra el código implementado** ¿a que te refieres?  ¿A que ves el código PHP tal cual lo estamos viendo en la pregunta?

Comment: Si te refieres a que no te está direccionando a una vista en especifico prueba agregando `header('Location: tu_archivo.php');` al final de un `IF/ELSE`

Comment: muchas gracias chicos